# How do I set PHP's $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] from node?

Tags: php, node.js, http

The situation is that we have a rest API written in PHP. When a user sends a request to our site, we are calling a node script to call the rest API to get JSON and return a rendered javascript template to output onto the page.

But, in the rest script there is a check to make sure that `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` is the same as `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. When I navigate to the rest URL via my browser, `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` is set correctly, but when I make a `get` request from the node script, it is left blank.

I tried setting an `Origin` header. This is what I googled:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin

So my request in node was:

```
https.get({
    path:path,
    headers:{
        "Origin": "http://example.com"
    }
},function(res){
    ..etc
```

But `error_log`ing `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` reveals that it is still blank.

How do I make it so that PHP knows that `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` is the current server?

Thanks!

Comment: [How secure is HTTP_ORIGIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566378/how-secure-is-http-origin)

Comment: Related? [Spoof Origin header in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135508/spoof-origin-header-in-node-js).